Java flexible app engine random cross origin failures
We have a google cloud app engine java instance and we are connecting to it from a web site via rest API. We have agents in South Africa and America. It seems that sometimes it has intermittent issues in America but then during these times the staff in America don't have the same issue and vice versa. I managed to replicate the issue and it seems that a request will fail with a CORS error but then a few seconds later I will try again and the same API call will go through. Please see the error below. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/Customer/getCustomerMemberships?customerId=225443&_dc=1717180349400&page=1&offset=0&totalMemberInstitutionPolicy=5' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried using the application and I was expecting the API requests to go through consistently as they usually do but I randomly get CORS exceptions and it is not on the same API call either, it is just random.

This sounds like a caching issue. Do your responses (even those to non-CORS requests) list Origin in a Vary header?
